# Best pattern to create sha256 from file and store file

Tags: go

I am writing a webserver that receives a file as an upload as `multipart/form-data`. I am generating the file sha256 from the request but due to the nature of the `Reader` interface, I can't reuse the data to also upload the file to a filer. These files can be a few hundred `MB`s. What is the best way to store the content? I can duplicate the contents but I am worried that could be wasteful on memory resources.

EDIT

```
func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := r.MultipartForm.File["capture"][0].Open()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    hash, err := createSha(f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
}

func createSha(image multipart.File) (hash.Hash, error) {
    sha := sha256.New()
    // This cause the contents of image to no longer be available to be read again to be stored on the filer
    if _, err := io.Copy(sha, image); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return sha, nil
}
```

Comment: Without any code, you question is hard to answer. Could you provide the part of your program that handles the upload?

Comment: You probably want an [`io.TeeReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader)?

Comment: And probably do a Seek(0, io.SeekStart) on the reader before that.

Comment: @mbuechmann: That won't work for an HTTP response, as the [response Body is just an io.ReadCloser](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response), not an `io.Seeker`.

Comment: show some code.

Comment: @Flimzy I thought of reading the file via `FormFile` of the `http.Request`. That returns a `multipart.File`, which implements `Seeker`. But without any provided code, we have to guess...

Comment: @mbuechmann: Very well.  And agreed, we need code!

Comment: thanks for responding, I added the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`io.MultiWriter(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter) to send the data to multiple output streams concurrently, such as a hash and some remote writer.

For example (roughly):

```
sha := sha256.New()
filer := filer.New(...) // Some Writer that stores the bytes for you?
err := io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(sha, filer), r)
// TODO: handle error
// Now sha.Sum(nil) has the file digest and "filer" got sent all the bytes.
```

Note that `io.Multiwriter` can take as many writers as you want, so you could compute additional hashes at the same time (e.g. md5, sha1, etc.) or even send the file to multiple locations, e.g.:

```
md5, sha1, sha256, sha512 := md5.New(), sha1.New(), sha256.New(), sha512.New()
s3Writer, gcsWriter := filer.NewS3Writer(), filer.NewGCSWriter()
mw := io.MultiWriter(awsWriter, gcsWriter, md5, sha1, sha256, sha512)
err := io.Copy(mw, r)
// TODO: handle error
// Now you've got all the hashes for the file and it's stored in the cloud.
```